# How do I use the args and Question argument at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get my bot to paste whatever someone types to a message and not allow them to use the command when they don't type anything, so using `&test random text` it'll display `random text` and if I do `&test` it'll display an error saying `you have to type something in` or something like that,

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import random
from discord import Member, Embed
from discord.ext.commands import BucketType, cooldown
from discord.ext.commands import errors
import asyncio


@client.command()
@cooldown(4, 11, BucketType.user)
async def test(ctx, args, *, question):
   response = ""
   for arg in args:
      response = response + " " + arg
 
   embed=discord.Embed(title="\"" + response + "\"", colour=ctx.author.colour)
   embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
   somegifs = random.choice(gifs)
   embed.set_image(url=somegifs)
   embed.set_footer(text="Test embed")
   await ctx.send(embed=embed)
@test.error
async def test_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        embed2 = discord.Embed(title="you have to type something in", colour=ctx.author.colour)
        embed2.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        embed2.set_footer(text="Test embed")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed2)
    else: raise(error)
```

This is what I'm using, every time I use the command, text or not, it'll display the error message,
Edit: after testing the command again, it does respond but only when you type more than one word and it only displays the first word with spaces between the letters [as shown here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/803775364488757318/806205824695271464/20210202_165347.jpg)

Comment: What is the problem, is there any error?

Comment: It displays the error as a message when using the command by itself and when using the command with only one word, it displays only the first word when you use more than one word anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can just format the command like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *, args):
    await ctx.send(args)
```

And then your error handling and all that after that

Comment: True, you don't need that extra step, thanks. I'll edit it